# Running all browserified Mocha tests in folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, browserify

I have an browser javascript app which uses **browserify** and **Mocha** tests which are run in **Phantom.js** and other browsers.

The tests use a `test/tests.js` file as an entry point where I require each file:

```
// ...
// Require test files here:
require('./framework/extendable.test');
require('./framework/creator.test');
require('./framework/container.test');
require('./framework/api_client.test');
// ...
```

**This is very tedious and I would like to be able to require the entire folder.**

I have tried using [**include-folder**](https://github.com/parroit/include-folder) which only loads the contents of each file (I don´t want to `eval` for obvious reasons).

I have also looked at [**require-dir**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/require-dir) but Browserify does not seem to pick up on the require calls.

Comment: I disagree that this is tedious. This is how node works and I think explicit behavior is much better than implicit behavior.

Comment: Also look at [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/)

Comment: This is one case where I don´t really need explicit behaviour. I would be even more happy if it could randomise the order they are required in.

Comment: @naomik Node allows you to define an index.js file in a folder, which may dynamically discover (and require) all the other files in that folder. So in fact Node would let the OP do exactly what they want. If Node lacked this facility, that would be tedious. But it doesn't, so it isn't.

Comment: @papirtiger The accepted answer doesn't answer the question in the title, which is unfortunate for anyone searching for an answer to that question. Could you change the title of your question to the problem that the accepted answer actually solved? Thanks!

Comment: @DanielEarwicker, I never said node couldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Karma (https://github.com/karma-runner/karma) to run your Mocha tests in multiple browsers (PhantomJS, FF, IE, locally or remote via WebDriver, as you want).

Then you can use the karma-bro (https://github.com/Nikku/karma-bro) preprocessor. It will bundle your tests on the fly with browserify, only for the testing purposes.

So you can just specify the folder, that contains your tests, in the Karma config.

That's the way I do it.

Comment: I guess if I can specify a glob in `karma.config.js` than I won´t really need to browserify my tests. I was just using browserify to pull in all the files so that I didn´t need to keep adding script tags to my `TestRunner.html`. So off to learn Karma then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's right. You would only need it, if you use node's require() to include modules.

Comment: There is also Mochify (https://github.com/mantoni/mochify.js) which was build exactly for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own simple transform that will simply replace specified folder name with the list of require calls. Even with the random in place if necessary. It's not that hard. I am making many transforms for myself to ease up on stuff like this.

Comment: I guess I could use something like [Concatenify](https://github.com/trodrigues/concatenify) but I have already got Karma set up and I like the fact that I can get a correct file / line number even when running though Phantom.js (gulp-mocha-phantomjs does not use the source maps, so you get a line in the munged files).